# Vim, how do I return to the place I was before pasting some yanked text?

Tags: vim

How do I return to the place I was before pasting some yanked text?

And then back to where I was immediately after pasting?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
`[
```

You can remap it if you'd like as well:

```
nnoremap p p`[
nnoremap P P`[
```

<kbd>`</kbd> jumps to a mark, and <kbd>[</kbd> marks the location of the ["first character of the previously changed or yanked text"](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html).

As for going back to where you were after pasting, well, it's the unsurprising `` `] ``.

If you ever have a similar problem, you can always check out which marks exist with `:marks`. Also, you might want to look at `` :help `[ `` for more details.

Answer (score 4):

`Ctrl-o` / `Ctrl-i` will jump you to older/newer locations.

e.g. `Ctrl-o` will take you back to your previous location, and `Ctrl-i` will send you to the later location.

See [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Jumping_to_previously_visited_locations) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am aware of Ctrl-o/Ctrl-i but it does not work in this case! :( Does not bring you to where you were before the PASTE of a yank!

Answer (score 1):

You could set a marker manually and return to it afterwards.

Setting a marker `a`:

```
ma
```

Returning to marker `a`

```
`a
```

Note that both commands have to be supplied in normal mode, and that no `:` is necessary before them. You can use any letter (not just `a`), and also use multiple markers at the same time.

Comment: This looks good, especially if I set the marker 'm' (faster to type for me).